# Postgres RDS sudden increase in IO:DataFileRead

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

We use AWS Postgres RDS, and for no apparent reason we have a sudden increase in IO:DataFileRead. We had this previously but a 2 days after it started we upgraded from Postgres 15.5 to 16.1 and doubled the size of the DB. afterwards we had no problem and than we downgraded the DB size back as we didn't really use all these resources. As you can see from the image below suddenly this problem occurs again out of no where. and its most visible at a time that there is minimum load on the DB for some reason.

would love to hear if some one has experience with similar problem and how to solve it

[image: RDS Waits]

*EDIT*:

just to be clear we do run a lot of select queries during the peaks and its ok, this is in contradiction original saying there is no special load, I mistook the timing. with that I do not care about the peaks they are OK. When I say "out of nowhere" I mean we generally had none IO:DataFileRead and suddenly it dominates the Waits. during peaks and not peaks increasing the overall waits exponentially compared to before the problem started (yes the peaks also became much "peakier")

Comment: It does not come out of nowhere it appears at roughly the same time each day. That is indicative of some cron based script/program running. I would look at Postgres log to see if this actually involves Postgres.  I don't use RDS so I don't know if there is such a thing, but you might look for system log to see what programs are running at that time.

Comment: RDS monitoring provides other views, like which query is causing/experiencing the waits, and how much IO was actually occurring (not just how long it was waited for).  Based on just this one graph, all we can say is what you already told us, "IO:DataFileRead increases suddenly".

Comment: @AdrianKlaver
we have crons they do not run at that time they actually start immediately after, but will try to check again

Comment: @jjanes I'm not talking about the peak all queries throughout the day went from almost 0 IO:DataFileRead to mostly IO:DataFileRead

Comment: @AdrianKlaver
my mistake there I misread the times its when the huge peak is when we start to index a lot of the DB to elastic so the peaks makes sense. But what I meant with the out of no where is the IO:DataFileRead starting dominating the Waits.

I don't care about the peaks there were always peaks they are just much "peakier" after the problem started

Comment: Look at the Postgres log and seeing if sheds light om what is going on.